# Auto-sizing height/width of north/west widgets on BorderLayoutContainer

Tags: gwt, gxt

It seems that `NorthSouthContainer` can ajust the height of north widget.
Can `BorderLayoutContainer` do the same one?

(gxt version: 3.1.1)

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final BorderLayoutContainer cont = new BorderLayoutContainer();
    // final NorthSouthContainer cont = new NorthSouthContainer();

    final ToolBar bar = new ToolBar();
    bar.add(new TextButton("tool bar"));

    cont.setNorthWidget(bar);

    final ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
    panel.setHeadingText("content panel");

    cont.setCenterWidget(panel);
    // cont.setSouthWidget(panel);

    final Viewport vp = new Viewport();
    vp.add(cont);
    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
}
```

`NorthSouthContainer`:

[image]

`BorderLayoutContainer`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are display bugs with that view.  I'm not sure if it can be dynamically sized, we specifically set the height for it.

```
final BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(<height>);
cont.setNorthWidget(bar, northData);
```

You may have to add the toolbar into another container that deals with size better, ours is a HorizontalLayoutContainer inside of a ContentPanel.